# MainActivity not closing even after closing it from other Activity

Tags: android

In my code, I have `MainActivity` as the launcher activity. Where it first checks where we are logged in or not by calling `checkLogin()` function from the `SessionManagementActivity`. The Function is called, and  meets the condition of "Not logged in". So, it should start the `LoginActivity` and end the `MainActivity` by `FLAG_CLEAR_TOP`. But the control again passes to the `MainActivity`, and there it starts executing the further code after the `checkLogin()` call. That is, the `MainActivity` is not closing from the `SessionManagementActivity`. Consequently my app first doesn't respond, it closes unexpectedly and then also starts `LoginActivity` successfully. And when I hit back, It again closes unexpectedly as it moves to `MainActivity`. Can anybody tell, why is the `MainActivity` not getting closed after `CheckLogin()`?

Here is the code

**MainActivity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    session = new SessionManagement(getApplicationContext());

    session.checkLogin();

    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();

    username = user.get(SessionManagement.KEY_NAME);

    school = user.get(SessionManagement.KEY_SCHOOL);
```

**SessionManagement.java**

```
// Editor for Shared preferences
Editor editor;

// Context
Context _context;

// Shared pref mode
int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

// Sharedpref file name
private static final String PREF_NAME = "iguardian";

// All Shared Preferences Keys
private static final String IS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn";

// User name (make variable public to access from outside)
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";

// Email address (make variable public to access from outside)
public static final String KEY_SCHOOL = "school";

// Constructor
public SessionManagement(Context context){
    this._context = context;
    pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = pref.edit();
}

/**
 * Create login session
 * */
public void createLoginSession(String username, String school){
    // Storing login value as TRUE
    editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);

    // Storing name in pref
    editor.putString(KEY_NAME, username);

    // Storing email in pref
    editor.putString(KEY_SCHOOL, school);

    // commit changes
    editor.commit();
}   


/**
 * Check login method wil check user login status
 * If false it will redirect user to login page
 * Else won't do anything
 * */
public void checkLogin(){
    Log.i("Value of ","check");
    // Check login status
    if(!this.isLoggedIn()){


        Intent i = new Intent(_context, LoginActivity.class);

        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);


        // Add new Flag to start new Activity
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);


        // Staring Login Activity
        _context.startActivity(i);



    }

}
```

**Logs**

```
01-01 19:17:51.617: E/AndroidRuntime(12017): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-01 19:17:51.617: E/AndroidRuntime(12017): Process: com.litchi.iguardian, PID: 12017
01-01 19:17:51.617: E/AndroidRuntime(12017): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.litchi.iguardian/com.litchi.iguardian.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-01 19:17:51.617: E/AndroidRuntime(12017):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
01-01 19:17:51.617: E/AndroidRuntime(12017):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
01-01 19:17:51.617: E/AndroidRuntime(12017):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
01-01 19:17:51.617: E/AndroidRuntime(12017):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
01-01 19:17:51.617: E/AndroidRuntime(12017):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-01 19:17:51.617: E/AndroidRuntime(12017):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-01 19:17:51.617: E/AndroidRuntime(12017):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
01-01 19:17:51.617: E/AndroidRuntime(12017):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-01 19:17:51.617: E/AndroidRuntime(12017):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-01 19:17:51.617: E/AndroidRuntime(12017):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
01-01 19:17:51.617: E/AndroidRuntime(12017):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
01-01 19:17:51.617: E/AndroidRuntime(12017):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-01 19:17:51.617: E/AndroidRuntime(12017): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-01 19:17:51.617: E/AndroidRuntime(12017):    at com.litchi.iguardian.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:152)
01-01 19:17:51.617: E/AndroidRuntime(12017):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
01-01 19:17:51.617: E/AndroidRuntime(12017):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
01-01 19:17:51.617: E/AndroidRuntime(12017):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
01-01 19:17:51.617: E/AndroidRuntime(12017):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Finish main activity when you start your login activiry

Comment: Did that as well. But it did not close even by doing so.

Comment: How you are doing that??

Answer (score 0):

Get **boolean** result from **checkLogin()** and start activity from **MainActivity**
Change the statement from

```
_context.startActivity(i);
```

to

```
_context.startActivityForResult(i, requestCode);
```

*Refere* this link for `startActivityForResult`

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

**Edit 2 :**
**SessionManagement.java**

```
public boolean checkLogin(){
    Log.i("Value of ","check");
    // Check login status
    if(!this.isLoggedIn()){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
boolean b = session.checkLogin();
    if(!b) {
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    ...
            _context.startActivityForResult(i, 1);
    }


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: an int that you decide.

Comment: com.litchi.iguardian.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:152)...........Which statement on Line no  152

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!this.isLoggedIn()){


    Intent i = new Intent(_context, LoginActivity.class);

    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);


    // Add new Flag to start new Activity
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);


    // Staring Login Activity
    _context.startActivity(i);
```

((Activity)_context).finish();

```
}
```